# Ignore tags from tag endpoint

Tags: feature-request

Currently, the way to ignore tags is to add it to the list from within your settings. I find it would be very beneficial to click on a tag and have the option to ignore this tag from the page so I don't have to go to my settings page to do so.

It would also mean I don't have to remember each tag I wish to ignore, or go to the settings page each time I find one I wish to ignore.

Comment: @Floern Cool, still learning something new here everyday.