# Easier links to "favourite" a tag

Tags: feature-request

Somewhat strangely, there is no link to favorite a tag in either of the two obvious places:

- When searching for [tagname]. ([For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js))
- When viewing the Tag Info page for it ([For example](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vue.js/info)).

The only way to favorite it is to explicitly go to "edit" under Favourite Tags, which seems a bit backwards and clunky.

Comment: Also raised here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318321/ignore-tags-from-tag-endpoint?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

When you hover over any tag and the black box appears, use the star in the top left corner of that box. It'll be:

- a grey star if it is neither favorited or ignored.
- a yellow star if it is favorites.
- a red cross if it is ignored.

Comment: Wow. Honestly, that never occurred to me. I even very carefully checked to see that I hadn't missed something, on each of these pages. Is that evidence that this feature is not discoverable? :) In particular, there's a 1 second delay before the popup, during which I have usually clicked on the tag, so I never see it.

Comment: I'll also point out that the star ⭐️ symbol is not used anywhere else to indicate that a tag is favourited. It's not in the "Favorite Tags" side bar panel, it's not on the Tags page, it's not on either of the pages I mentioned.